# EXTJS close a window

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a Window. I'm having some issues with the default close button which is on the top-right hand corner of the window. Therefore i was thinking to disable that close button and add a close button so that when the user clicks will disable/remove the window. What is the code to remove/close the Window.

The Window definition is as follows;

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyWin', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.mywin',
......
```

Comment: You want to remove the close button just to add another button that looks and does exacly the same?

Comment: I don't think you can do that (but if it's possible please do share). I want to add a normal button, then name it close, and upon clicking it to close the Window.

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/X43Fz/

Comment: SO in my case is it mywin.close(); ?

Comment: If `mywin` is the variable holding an instance of your window, yes. The code you showed does not open any window, so we can't tell you how to close that window in particular. See my answer for a window that closes itself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's just `close()`.

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/87DgZ/):

```
new Ext.window.Window({
    title: 'A window',
    closable: false, // hides the normal close button
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    bbar: [
        {
            text: 'Close',
            handler: function () { this.up('window').close(); }
        }
    ],
    autoShow: true
});
```

Comment: Dot selector ('.window') is deprecated in latest versions of Extjs. Use ('window') without dot instead.

Comment: Since question asker tagged the question with extjs4 I guess this is not an issue @yurin